# How to keep ASP.NET Blazor WebAssembly client pages alive to prevent reloading when navigating back?

Tags: asp.net, navigation, blazor, singleton, blazor-webassembly

In an ASP.NET Blazor WebAssembly Client, when the user navigates away from page A (by using a browser button, a navigation menu item, etc) to page B *within the same SPA*, page A is disposed, then page B is constructed.

If the user navigates back to page A (once again using the browser back button, a menu item, etc), the page is entirely recreated (including fetching back its data from the server) and its scroll position is reset to the top. This is contrary to the common expectation that if I navigate back to a page, I should find it in the way it was when I left it.

I obviously see ways of "fixing" this but I am wondering what is the commonly accepted way to solve that issue ? Can the pages be made as singleton instead of transient ? Or do I really need to keep the loaded data and track the scroll position in my own singleton separate from the page ?

Answer (score 1):

The site only reloads when you navigate to a url outside the SPA i.e. hot the back button to the page you were on prior to loading the SPA.

You can prevent navigation outside the SPA session using the `NavigationLock` component.

Add this to `App`:

```cs
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
<NavigationLock ConfirmExternalNavigation=true />
```

And you will get asked to confirm you want to leave the site.

[image]

If you want to maintain state across loads, then you will need to introduce state management into your components and store the state in the browser local storage.

Comment: My question is actually WITHIN THE SPA as I mentionned. Page A and B are both within the SPA. When I navigate from A to B, I see that A is disposed. So when I navigate back from B to A, A needs to be re-created, its data refetched, and its scroll position is lost. I am wondering how people usually solve this problem.

Comment: Are you talking about within a list, and if so what grid/list are you using?  Personally I use paging and have a `ListState` object, and use modals over the list for editing/viewing a specific row.

Comment: I am talking about very basic WebAssembly Blazor pages. I believe in your example above, "Home" and "Counter" are two pages. If a user is in the Counter page and has started to interact with it and/or scroll down its content, and then they click the "Home" menu item, the Counter component is DISPOSED. So if the user hits "Back", it indeed goes back to "Counter", but the component is re-instanciated and they have lost whatever they were doing and the position they were scrolled at. Expected behavior is when hitting "Back" you should find the page the way it was.